# How to change some part of address with javascript and navigate to that address?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I what to change -

```
www.site.com/img-small-1.jpg
```

to

```
www.site.com/img-large-1.jpg
```

How can i do this using javascript?

Comment: You can use replace() in javascript, what is the issue?

Comment: I can't see any errors in your code.

Comment: `"www.site.com/img-small-1.jpg".replace("small", "large")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace to change the address,

```
var currentAddress = "www.site.com/img-small-1.jpg";
var newAddress = currentAddress.replace("img-small-1.jpg", "img-large-1.jpg");
window.location.href = newAddress; // this will redirect to new address
```